# Return generic superclass from a function instead of subclass

Tags: scala, generics

If I have an abstract class `Location` and two subclasses as follows

```
abstract class Location[L <: Location[L]]

case class Loc1(name: String) extends Location[Loc1]
case class Loc2(name: String) extends Location[Loc2]

def getLoc[L <: Location[L]](x: Boolean): L =
  if (x) Loc1("1")
  else Loc2("2")
```

Calls to `getLoc` will result in a type mismatch as it requires an `L` but sees `Loc1` or `Loc2`. How can I get it to return the specific subclasses but as the super class `L` or `Location[L]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of parameterization of a class or a trait with its subclass is called F-bounded polymorphism. It's useful when you want to have some trait such as Location, but you want its fields to return actual subtypes of Location, not the generic Location itself. This is very useful in e.g. builder patterns.

In your case, that would be something like

```
abstract class Location[L <: Location[L]] {
  val getLoc: L
}

case class Loc1(name: String) extends Location[Loc1] {
  def getLoc: Loc1 = this
}

case class Loc2(name: String) extends Location[Loc2] {
  def getLoc: Loc2 = this
}
```

Note how Location has a field `getLoc` whose return type is whatever Location was parameterized with.

This way you can have some generic code that works with some value `v` of type `Location`, but calling `V.getLoc` will return the actual subtype of Location that was used when you defined `v`. So if you had `val v: Location[Berlin]`, you could obtain `v.getLoc` of type Berlin, instead of obtaining a more general type `Location`, which is handy.

However, your example doesn't seem to be of this nature. **Your boolean makes things complicated;** you can't have a return type that's "sometimes Loc1, sometimes Loc2, depending on how you parameterized the function". What if I call `getLoc[Loc1](false)`? As long as you have that boolean, you can't be specific in the return type, not even with F-bounded polymorphism. You have to be honest to your users and admit that all you can safely say about the return type is that it's some Location. But for this you don't even need the FBP, you can simply say:

```
abstract class Location

case class Loc1(name: String) extends Location
case class Loc2(name: String) extends Location

def getLoc(x: Boolean): Location =
  if (x) Loc1("1")
  else Loc2("2")
```

You could also use a sum-type, which comes down to the similar principle as subtyping. So you would say that your return type is `Either[Loc1, Loc2]`. (Scala 3 will allow true unions, so you could say `Loc1 | Loc2`). But you can't say "here, parameterize your method with L and that will be the return type", giving the user false hope that they have control over the return type and that it's actually going to be whichever L they desired, and then you use this evil boolean which can rig the return type into something else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know what `x` is at compile time, you lose the exact type information about the returned value. You can no longer tell `Loc1` from `Loc2` apart. You only know that the returned type is a `Location[L]` for some type `L`. This type can be written in Scala as

```
Location[L] forSome { type L }
```

which in this case can be shortened to

```
Location[_]
```

Thus, if you adjust `getLoc` as follows:

```
def getLoc(x: Boolean): Location[_] =
  if (x) Loc1("1")
  else Loc2("2")
```

then your code compiles again.

The following also works:

```
def getLoc(x: Boolean): Location[L] forSome { type L } =
  if (x) Loc1("1")
  else Loc2("2")
```

Comment: It feels (to me) like going to existential for this isn't the approach here. It looks to me like OP is having a bit of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Agreed: it's unclear why someone would want to introduce a rather heavyweight F-bounded polymorphism (used to track precise information about the types), and then immediately throw away all the type information and use existentials...